# IntelliJ: Cannot resolve symbol 'String'

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Regarding the following code:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

My InteliJ marks `String` in red, saying:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'String'

Comment: Have you configured a JDK to use in the project?  (On windows: ) File > Project Structure > JDK.  Additionally, clicking {ALT} + {ENTER} on the word underlined in red will likely come up with a suggestion (with a link) on how to resolve it.

Comment: Make sure you have your JDK set up for making String available in your classpath.

Comment: @BeUndead thanks, that solved the problem.